# Acrobat plugin not working in Waterfox

Tags: adobe-acrobat, browser-plugin

I'm using [Waterfox 10](http://waterfoxproject.org/) browser in Windows 7 Home Premium and I just installed Adobe Acrobat X Pro but there is no browser integration for PDFs. If I click a PDF link while browsing, it always asks me to open (i.e. download) the file in an application (Adobe Acrobat). I want it to be displayed inside the browser.

I have Firefox 10 and Chrome installed on the same machine and it works fine there.

I also tried installing Acrobat Reader X (10.1.2) from Adobe site and it doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried copying the plugin from the firefox folder to the waterfox folder?

Comment: Which file am I suppose to copy exactly?

Comment: There should be a `dll` in the plugins folder. Unfortunately, I don't have that plugin or waterfox so I can't help with specifics, sorry.

Comment: Don't know where to find that plugin folder so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox` should be the default install.

Comment: There is no `AdobeAcrobat.dll` or anything similar in there... Do you know the name for that plugin?

Comment: try `amtlib.dll` Be sure to copy, not move it

Comment: No, it is still just trying to download PDFs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Adobe Acrobat browser plugin is not 64 bit, it obviously isn't working.
There is no workaround that I know off but if you'd like to open PDFs inside your browser, you can use [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pdfjs/) Firefox/Waterfox plugin.